# Regex: how to match list of specific domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regex which will match a specific list of domains in e-mail addresses.
I know this is probably not a popular issue, but it's for internal use, and for a limited list of e-mail addresses. I have like 10-12 domains that I need to be able to match.

The domain names do not contain sub domains or dots and the suffix is always the same, like:

```
*@onedomain.com
*@anotherdomain.com
*@thirddomain.com
```

I have tried with this:

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@(?i)(onedomain|anotherdomain|thirddomain|domain4)\.com$/
```

But I get this error: Invalid syntax.
Can anybody help with this, please?
Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? I don't see any syntax error in this regex.

Comment: Javascript/jQuery - I'm using the regex in the JQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't use `(?i)` with javascript regex.

You have to use the `/i` modifier instead.

```
pattern = new RegExp('^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@(onedomain|anotherdomain|thirddomain|domain4)\.com$','i')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a regex solution, but if the list of domains is long, you might want to consider not doing it purely in regex. 10-12 domains could make for one long nasty expression.

Instead you can use regex to match a basic email format, and then keep an array of whitelisted domains that are allowed. That way you don't need to put all the domains into the expression itself.

```
function isValidEmail(address) {
    var domains = ["onedomain","anotherdomain","thirddomain","domain4"];

    // Basic .com email matching
    var regex = /^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*@(.*)\.com$/i;
    var matches = regex.exec(email);

    // Assert that address is an .com email address 
    if (matches === null)
        return false;

    // return true if domain is in whitelist, false otherwise
    return (domains.indexOf(matches[1]) != -1);
}
```

Changing `@(.*)\.com` to `@(.*\..{2,})` will enable you to put the full domain in the whitelist array should you need to match other domains than `.com` you'd then have to put `domain4.com` etc. in the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is about the regex, you could try this :

```
/^[\w-\.]+@domain(1|2|3|4)\.com$/
```

About your regex : I think the syntax error is in the `(?i)` part. I don't really see what is this group for, and it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to make it NOT case sensitive.

Comment: @Meek I see. To make your regex case insensitive, you have to add the i at the end, like this : `/pattern/i`. In my regex, i used \w, which isn't case sensitive. I hope this will answer your question !

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex to match @domainX.com:

```
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+-/=?^_`\.{|}~]+@domain[1-4]\.com
```

it matches

```
test@domain1.com
user123@domain4.com
```

and much more

**EDIT**

to match every domain use this regex:

```
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+-/=?^_`\.{|}~]+@([a-z0-9_-]+[\.]?)*
```

Comment: Thanks. The domains will not necessary have numbers 1-4 in their names - it was just an example. The domain names will be different. Sorry.

Comment: ok, take a look at my edit. This regex also allows subdomains

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I mean, I would like to test a list of specific domains - not just any domain. I have like 10-12 domains that I need to be able to match. :-)